# gradle: How to package a static library (.a) into aar

Tags: gradle, package, aar

I am build a module with gradle, and need to package some static libraries into aar file, but I find gradle only package dynamic libraries. How to package a  static library (.a) into aar?

Comment: Hello, did you manage to find a solution to this by any chance? I know it's a long shot considering the date you posted at, but I'm facing the same issue right now... Thanks in advance.

Comment: actually, I solved it by replacing the static library with a dynamic library. gradle  do not support packaging a static library into aar

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! :) That's what I ended up doing as well! Cheers!